# Which home modems and other network gear for reliability?

Tags: router, home-networking, modem

Do you have a home modem/router that occasionally doesn't function exactly like it should. I find this weird behavior completely unpredictable and I can only guess that maybe it is overheating. Does this happen with all home network gear as they prefer to not add fans to keep noise to a minimum.

What brand of home networking gear have you used for at least 2 years without ever requiring a restart?

Answer (score 2):

Routers? None. Well except a Cisco ASA device, but I wouldn't call it a "normal" home router/firewall.

Switches: I've always had great luck with Netgear switches at home.

Answer (score 2):

I've had really good experience with Asus WL-500g router. I've installed openwrt on it and I don't remember when I had to reboot it last...

WRT54g can also be quite reliable if you flash a different firmware on it (openwrt seems to be very stable)

Comment: Same here, for the last 1.5 years, except with DD-WRT Mega.  Very stable.

Answer (score 2):

I run a pair of older [ZyXEL](http://us.zyxel.com/) routers: an [x550](http://us.zyxel.com/Products/details.aspx?PC1IndexFlag=20040520161256&CategoryGroupNo=PDCA2008013) functions as the main brain which handles all of the heavy lifting (DHCP, QoS, NAT, etc.) and a [p330](http://us.zyxel.com/Products/details.aspx?PC1IndexFlag=20040520161256&CategoryGroupNo=PDCA2007047) sits behind my TV to provide access to items in my entertainment center. The p330 connects back to the x550 via wifi so I do not have to run Ethernet cable all over the house. Despite the back-and-forth traffic this setup creates between the two routers I have not noticed a significant speed hit to my wireless devices.

I have experienced *one* failure in this setup in the 3 years it has been running and that was when a power surge killed my x550 which ZyXEL replaced under warranty.

Both of my units have been discontinued in favor of Wireless N models and I plan on upgrading if/when these start to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much you're going to find "home network" aka consumer-grade equipment that is reliable enough to never "require" a restart. There's a varying degree of quality, and consumer experiences, much like with phone companies. Everyone's had a problem with **some** brand, and advises everyone against that.

Personally, I've had the best luck with:

Routers: Linksys WRT54G, though I replace the stock firmware with DD-WRT (mainly for the VPN feature and the less crappy interface). D-Link DGL4100, while I don't like the interface much and it doesn't take any 3rd party firmware, it's been a pretty reliable device.

Switches: D-Link 8 port gigabit switch (don't remember the model #) and a variety of netgear 8 port 100mb switches.

Answer (score 0):

Have had great experience with Vigor routers from [Draytek](http://www.draytek.com)

Answer (score 0):

I really like my netgear router.  I've been using it for 3 years and it runs like a champ.

I had a linksys and a D-Link before that.  The wireless was very unreliable on both.  I settled on netgear because it just worked.  I never lose wireless.  The only time I lose internet connection is because of my ISP.  My internal network never goes down.  I'd recommend netgear to anyone.